# IdentityServer3 locking on parallel requests

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, identityserver3

I have an auth server built that is using IdentityServer3. Yesterday when we were writing a dashboard page we ran into an interesting issue.

The dashboard makes a request to our protected api, this bring the dashboard config down. In here we have all the graphs that need to be loaded. We then map the graphs array to a function that builds up the api request with the token and sends the request to the api to get the data for the individual graphs. This is where the problem arises. It seems we might be hitting some sort of brute force protection because IdentityServer3 locks up and doesnt return a response. 
If i execute the requests in series though, there is no issue and everything works fine. It is only when it is in parallel that there is an issue.

I can replicate this by creating a very basic in memory IdSrv3 implementation and using the below linq. If you switch out the await line for the two commented lines than the issue comes up.

```
    async Task Main()
    {
        var authApi = "http://localhost/identityserver/";
        var tasks = new List<Task<bool>>();
        var tokens = new[] {"b2645fd8c4958449ce5e43de4d49db68","b2645fd8c4958449ce5e43de4d49db68","3c1af0ac17f16f09e4c342836dc13b77"};

        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++)
        {
            // tasks.Add(Execute(authApi, tokens[i]));
            await Execute(authApi, tokens[i]);
        }

        //var res = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    HttpClient CreateClient(string baseUrl)
    {
        var http = new HttpClient();

        http.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
        http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "bmljZXRyeTphc3Nob2xl");

        return http;
    }

    async Task<bool> Execute(string authApi, string token)
    {
        using (var http = CreateClient(authApi))
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            values.Add("token", token);

            HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
            var response = await http.PostAsync("/identityserver/connect/accesstokenvalidation", content);

            Console.WriteLine($"Is Status Success: {response.IsSuccessStatusCode}");

            return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
        }
    }
```

Is this a bug in IdentityServer3? or is it some kind of brute force protection or fraud detection security feature ? How would i go about fixing this?

Comment: Skimming the code, it looks like it should be ok. Please look deeper into it and if you find there is a problem in IdentityServer, then open an issue in the github issue tracker explaining what's wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Worked out what it was. The logging detection framework that you guys are using was not detecting NLog and i wrote some reflection code to better detect it and it worked but it was what created the issue with parralell request

Comment: @BrockAllen do you have a link to that GitHub issue? Thanks

Comment: In the end it was more of an issue because of how I was trying to get access to the logging solution